# Drupal Views Multiple Field CiviCRM

Tags: civicase, drupal-views

I collect data in case activities, and I'm currently trying to build a Drupal Views of this data. I'm running into a problem with multiple fields. For example: "What colors do you prefer?" The results are showing up like:

Red, Blue, Green
Green, Blue

Is there a way to present each line as a color? My end goal is to create a pivot table to show a count of each color. I have a lot of multiple field questions that have this problem right now. The only solution I can think of is to create a PHP code to output a if statement == "RED" line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Charts, Google Charts module - if not for this purpose you'll be using it for some other data displays soon!

Below is a screenshot of a View - Page of Format: Chart -> aggregating by Grant Type over a certain time period [PS - the Table is an attachment -> Format: table]. For your use case try Aggregate by your custom field containing the Colors.

[image]

Comment: This would have been really awesome, but Views is treating Civicrm multi-fields as one field. Therefore, "Red, Green" can't be split up.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest indeed that you use a php field in your views and a field per option and filter the options out.

The multi value custom fields store their value with a special character as a separator.